# Java Updates Restrict Unsafe SSL Renegotiation With Active Directory Servers

Tags: tls, java, secure-renegotiation

We have two active directory (AD) hosts, `ead01.domain.com` and `ead02.domain.com`; we also have a corresponding service domain, at `eadauth.domain.com` which round-robins between these AD hosts (via DNS).

We have a ColdFusion application (CF runs on Java) that connects to the service domain over secure port 636. After upgrading our version of Java to 1.60_91 from 1.6.0_81, SSL handshakes now occasionally return this error:

```
jrpp-83, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = bad_certificate
jrpp-83, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
jrpp-83, called closeSocket()
jrpp-83, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: server certificate change is restricted during renegotiation
```

[Unsafe Renegotiation was disabled in 1.6.0_85](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/overview-156328.html).

`ead01.domain.com` has a SAN cert with these entries

```
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: ead01.domain.com
  DNSName: eadauth.domain.com
]
```

and `ead02.domain.com` has:

```
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: ead02.domain.com
  DNSName: eadauth.domain.com
]
```

My questions are: Should we generate and bind **one** new cert with SANs as follows on **both** hosts?

```
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: ead01.domain.com
  DNSName: ead02.domain.com
  DNSName: eadauth.domain.com
]
```

Are there any down sides to this setup? Any other options that we might consider, other than disabling unsafe renegotiation?

Comment: Since Java 1.6 reached no-more-updates end-of-life _2 years ago_, maybe you should see how 1.7 and 1.8 behave before changing your certificate setup?  You're going to have to upgrade to them within another 3 or 4 years no matter what.

Comment: @gowenfawr Java 1.7.0_71 and 1.8.0_25 do away with unsafe renegotiation too. Wondering, if it be possible to disable renegotiation on the server or even on the client?